# Specific mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql

The structure of my mysql table is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_hour_counts` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `subid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `unique_ids` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_ids` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `unique_ips` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_ips` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `global` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `time` text NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ind_1` (`date`,`time`(5),`subid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have an array of data like:

```php
$array = array(
    '0' => array(
        'date' => '2011-10-10',
        'time' => '00:00',
        'subid' => '2',
        'unique_ids' => '588'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'date' => '2011-10-10',
        'time' => '00:00',
        'subid' => '2',
        'unique_ips' => '3'
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'date' => '2011-10-10',
        'time' => '00:00',
        'subid' => '2',
        'total_ids' => '3995'
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'date' => '2011-10-10',
        'time' => '00:00',
        'subid' => '2',
        'total_ips' => '1000'
    ),
    '4' => array(
        'date' => '2011-10-10',
        'time' => '00:00',
        'subid' => '2',
        'global' => '1000'
    ),
    '5' => array(
        'date' => '2011-10-10',
        'time' => '01:00',
        'subid' => '3',
        'unique_ids' => '766'
    ),
    '6' => array(
        'date' => '2011-10-10',
        'time' => '01:00',
        'subid' => '3',
        'unique_ips' => '10'
    ),
    '7' => array(
        'date' => '2011-10-10',
        'time' => '01:00',
        'subid' => '3',
        'total_ids' => '934'
    ),
    '8' => array(
        'date' => '2011-10-10',
        'time' => '01:00',
        'subid' => '3',
        'total_ips' => '950'
    ),
    '9' => array(
        'date' => '2011-10-10',
        'time' => '01:00',
        'subid' => '3',
        'global' => '7554'
    )
);
```

The goal is to insert the data into the table. The result of inserting the data from this array should be the following:

[image: result]

I believe this could be done either by mysql request, or by preparing the array for usual insert.

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very messy, but:

```
// your array below
$array = array();

$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $item){
        $newArray[$item['subid']]['date'] = $item['date'];
        $item['time'] > $newArray[$item['subid']]['time'] ? $newArray[$item['subid']]['time'] = $item['time'] : null;
        $newArray[$item['subid']]['unique_ids'] += $item['unique_ids'];
        $newArray[$item['subid']]['total_ids'] += $item['total_ids'];
        $newArray[$item['subid']]['unique_ips'] += $item['unique_ips'];
        $newArray[$item['subid']]['total_ips'] += $item['total_ips'];
        $newArray[$item['subid']]['global'] += $item['global'];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

This gives you:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2011-10-10
            [time] => 00:00
            [unique_ids] => 588
            [total_ids] => 3995
            [unique_ips] => 3
            [total_ips] => 1000
            [global] => 1000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2011-10-10
            [time] => 01:00
            [unique_ids] => 766
            [total_ids] => 934
            [unique_ips] => 10
            [total_ips] => 950
            [global] => 7554
        )

)
```

You can then just do something like:

```
foreach($newArray as $key=>$value){
        echo "INSERT INTO `table` ('{$value['date']}',{$key},{$value['total_ids']})"; // etc. etc.
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the only correct answer, except i need `subid` field also in the subarray.

Comment: @hookman No you don't, its the array key (`$key`) - there's no need for dupe data.

Comment: @hookman: if you must, all you need to do is add `!isset($newArray[$item['subid']]['subid']) ? $newArray[$item['subid']]['subid'] = $item['subid'] : null;` to the first foreach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert depending of date, group the data in `$array` using php before inserting

Comment: What do you mean by "insert depending of date"? The database don't cares about it.

Comment: In see that some of `$array` elements don't contain data such a `unique_ids` but another items contain `total_ids`. On the screenshot you have all these data grouped by `date:time`.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (date,time,subid,unqiue_ids,unique_ips,total_ids,total_ips,global) VALUES (...)` This is one row. However, in the array, each subarray contains date,time,subid and unique_ids or unqiue_ips or total_ips or total_ids or global.

Comment: On the screenshot are two rows, some columns and no grouping. You cannot assume, that it has a meaning, that the date is the same. In the schema the `date`-column has no special meaning neither. But what I wanted to know: Where is the benefit in grouping the input data first?

Answer (score 1):

Once in a database, order is irrelevant.

Every call to retrieve data automatically sorts via data via a default column.

When you want to pull the data from the database you sort it via the SQL query.
ei.

```
SELECT date, subid, unique_ids, total_ids, unique_ips, total_ips, global, time FROM tb_hour_counts 
WHERE date = '2011-10-10'
ORDER BY time;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this answer connected with my question?

Comment: "Every call to retrieve data automatically sorts via data via a default column.". No, you cannot just assume a specific order as long as you don't specify it via `ORDER BY` (what you say yourself the next sentences ;))